# Get SHA for the first commit in git repository subdirectory, using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

How can I look up the SHA for the first commit in a repository subdirectory using libgit2sharp ?

On the command line I would do

> git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD